# Check installed MS Lync version from the registry

Tags: microsoft-office, skype, lync

To check the version of outlook that is installed, we have a nice 'centralized' registry key:

```
HKCR\Outlook.Application\CurVer = "Outlook.Application.XX"
```

By 'centralized', I mean that the key's path is always the same, regardless of the outlook version. 'XX' will give you the actual version installed, and also a way to access the outlook specific key:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Outlook
```

Is there a centralized way to check if **MS Lync/Skype for Business** is installed? I only know ways of checking it that depend on the version that is installed.

```
MOC/Lync2010: check -> Software\Microsoft\Communicator#InstallationDirectory
Lync 2013: check -> Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync\Capabilities#ApplicationName
Lync (from office 365): check -> Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync\InstallRoot#Path
Lync 2016: check -> ? Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\InstallRoot#Path (????)
```

Comment: Write a batch file that checks all 4 locations, using the `reg` command http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html

Comment: I already have that. The problem is that we have several components doing this same check, and every time there is a new Lync release we have to go searching all of them and change each one of them.

Comment: In Powershell: (gwmi Win32_Product | ?{$_.Name -like 'Microsoft Lync*'}).Version

Comment: You could do that in a batch with wmic, but powershell is way easier.